# PHP & HTML Form with javascript onsubmit not executed

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a HTML form asking for user input. A javascript function is meant to validate the form and should be triggered (using onsubmit) BEFORE executing the PHP code. (The js file is referenced in the header `<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>`)

HOWEVER the javascript is never executed and instead the PHP code executes and (correctly) includes the new file.

How can i make the javascript execute as required?

HTML file:

```
<form name="details" action="" method="post" 
     onSubmit="return ValidateForm(details);">
...
<input type="submit" name="post-this-form" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

PHP file:

```
if (isset($_POST['post-this-form']) and 
     $_POST['post-this-form'] == 'Next')
{
...
some php 
...
include 'shipping-details.html.php';
exit();
}
```

**EDIT**

here is the javascript as requested. It has been tested and worked without any PHP involved. By passing `details` (the name of the form) i'm making all the form fields accessible.

```
function ValidateForm(details)
        {
        var firstName=document.forms.details.firstName.value;
        var lastName=document.forms.details.lastName.value;
        var streetAddress=document.forms.details.streetAddress.value;
        var town=document.forms.details.town.value;
        var city=document.forms.details.city.value;
        var zip=document.forms.details.zip.value;
        var country=document.forms.details.country.value;       
        var creditCard=document.forms.details.creditcard.value;                 

                ...

        //Checks firstName
        if ((firstName=="")||(!firstName.match(alphabetExpression)))
            {
            alert ("Invalid first name, please re-enter");
            return false;
            }
                 ...

        //Checks creditCard
        if ((creditCard=="")||(!creditCard.match(numericExpression))||(creditCardLength!=16))
            {
            alert ("Invalid credit card entry, please re-enter");
            return false;
            }       
        }// end function
```

**EDIT 2**

i added `alert ("Hi");` to the start of the javascript and the alert never shows up which leads me to think that the function isn't executed at all.

**EDIT 3**

My initial suspicion that this problem could be due to PHP was wrong. As Jason mentioned in his comments the problem was in the javascript itself. It is a bit strange thought because the same javascript code worked "on its own" without PHP and on my local machine. So many factors to consider...thanks All for taking the time to have a look at my problem!

Comment: Could you please post your javascript code?

Comment: try to write `onSubmit="return ValidateForm(this);"` instead of `onSubmit="return ValidateForm(details);"`

Comment: What exactly are you intending to pass to your Javascript function? Because right now, you're telling it your passing a variable called details not the variable string 'details' which I'm guessing is what you intended.

Comment: @Ally - That's probably the issue, without being able to see the js

Comment: on a side note, why are you exit(); instead of return? is ValidateForm(details); returning false?

Comment: @jonathan exit(); is part of the php logic i implemented. could this interfere with the validate form function?

Comment: I bet there is a javascript error. Open error console. ctrl+shift+j in firefox.

Comment: @Jason, thanks, i'm getting closer...i checked as suggested and it says "ValidateForm is not defined"...however it is included in the header tag so it must be due to the PHP 'include' mechanism i implemented? no idea though how to fix that :(

Comment: @baba no, just a question about how your code is written, using exit() to break view displaying logic generally means improper serparation of concerns, since it's not directly realated to the question i posted it as a comment,  because that's what comments are for :)

Comment: @Jason further troubleshooting seems to point to my regular expressions in the javascript (not posted). Looks like errors are often where they are not expected :) thanks a lot for the tip to use the error console! If you post your comment, i'd be happy to accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Comment converted to answer***

"I bet there is a javascript error. Open error console. ctrl+shift+j in firefox."

Glad that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few things you must know the about the functions you are trying to build

```
function ValidateForm() {
     this; // this contains the form name no need for any variable declaration

     return true; // or false This is very important to continue the execution
                  // false stops the submittion
}
```

When you fix both of these issues, it should work as you want.

Comment: @orourkek, I am sorry you think so.

Comment: it does answer his question in a way, but before your edit you didn't even explain what he had to do... By the comments on the OP you can see I agree with you on the solution, but there was no actual answer to his question here, at the time